# Portlet Geolocation service in Liferay

Tags: geolocation, liferay, portlet

I am new to the topic of web portals, I am currently in a project for the creation of a portal in Liferay.

Someone has experience creating portlets for encapsulating a WMS geolocation service, it would be of great help to me if anyone has any tutorial.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.  Asking for tutorials is not appropriate for this site, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for guidance about topics, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for general advice.  If you have tried something and have a specific problem, please feel free to post about it!

Comment: You probably want to find associated articles here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liferay or post questions on unix.stackexchange.com